# How to only affect the unamed register on yank?

Tags: vim

I use yanking and putting a lot, but sometimes when my sequence of actions is yank X, put X, delete a line, put X, delete a line, put X, delete a line, I find myself wishing delete didn't fill the unnamed register.

How can I make it so only yank fills the unnamed register?

Comment: Do you want to make delete never fill the unnamed register, or is it sufficient to just have an option not to when you don't want it?

Comment: Have you thought about using a different register? The last yanked line will be in the `"0` register. See `:h quote0`

Comment: You could also delete into the blackhole register using `"_d`, but pasting from `"0` as @PeterRincker said is probably easier.

Comment: Great ideas! I ended up mapping `P` to `"0p` which has shift P always putting from the most recent yank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- Use the *blackhole register* for the deletes: `"_d`
- Recall the last yank from register 0: `"0p`